# PUT request: PHP code to Arduino HTTPClient

Tags: esp32, http

I'm uploading a file to Azure blob storage using REST API request. The file uploaded successfully using PHP curl request. But when I transfer the code into ESP32 HTTP client I'm getting an Authentication error. I also verify the HMAC key generated by the ESP32 Arduino code in PHP code.
I'm thinking that I'm missing something in adding header.
Here is my PHP code :

```
       $header = array (
        "x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob",
        "x-ms-date: " . $date,
        "x-ms-version: " . $version,
        "Authorization: SharedKey account_name:" . $signature_str,
        "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8",
        "Content-Length: " . strlen($fdata),
        );

    $url =  "https://acount_name.blob.core.windows.net/container/test.txt";
    $ch = curl_init ();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT' );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fdata);
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, True );
    echo($ch);
    curl_exec ( $ch );
```

and here is the corresponding Arduino IDE code:

```
    String sig = get_hmac();
      Serial.println(sig);

      if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) { //Check WiFi connection status
        HTTPClient http;
        http.begin("https://account_name.blob.core.windows.net/container/test.txt");  //Specify destination for HTTP request

        http.addHeader("x-ms-blob-type", "BlockBlob");
        http.addHeader("x-ms-date", Date);
        http.addHeader("x-ms-version", "2018-03-28");
        http.addHeader("Authorization", "SharedKey account_name:"+sig);
        http.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
        http.addHeader("Content-Length",  "20");

        int httpResponseCode = http.PUT(d);   
        if (httpResponseCode > 0) {
          String response = http.getString(); 
          Serial.println(httpResponseCode);   
          Serial.println(response);        
        } else {
          Serial.print("Error on sending POST: ");
          Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
        }
        http.end();  //Free resources
      } else {
        Serial.println("Error in WiFi connection");
      }
```

The error I'm getting is :

> The MAC signature found in the HTTP request
>   'sVrSFpplX+Gkcb4R/iSDf6eqUP4srkZuVD68/pAeYwE=' is not the same as any
>   computed   signature.....

Although the HMAC signature created from same String works in PHP
here is the reference page of the API:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob
Thanks

Comment: the `http.PUT(d);` adds the Content-length header, Host header, User-Agent header, Accept-Encoding header and Connection header. Is it OK for the SharedKey authorization?

Comment: It looks like that error message is coming from the web-service; seems like this might be more debugging the webservice, than arudino. What status code are you getting?

Comment: the first code uses 'SharedKey mikeiot,' the second code uses 'SharedKey account_name:' could this be the problem? You are also hard coding the content-length in the second code, could you be sending an incorrect amount?

Comment: @Juraj I need custom header like given in Arduino code 'addHeader'. It's ok to send these headers. should I skip Content-length header?

Comment: @esoterik I'm getting 403 response code from the server and the error message shown in post

Comment: @esoterik the acount_name is same in the code just change in the post description. Now I have edited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got clue from @esoterik answer and manage to send request successfully.
The problem were in adding header parameter:

```
 http.addHeader("Content-Length",  "20");
```

This duplicate the header( 2nd one added in PUT method). I just comment it and the code works.
Thanks for every one response